# "to whom I am talking with" -- is "to" or "with" redundant?

Tags: prepositions, american-english

My friend was like

> You are the first member here on facebook to whom I am talking with.

Shouldn't it be like "you are […] facebook to whom I am talking"? I think one of the words is redundant — I mean, "to" and "with".

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Only one preposition is needed. So it could be *You are the first person on Facebook with whom I am talking* or *You are the first person on Facebook to whom I am talking.* That said, the  construction should probably be, *you are ...with whom I have spoken.*